# ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-joyride/assets/images/close.svg in ngx-joyride

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I am doing the build then ngx-joyride giving me a error i.e.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-joyride/assets/images/close.svg
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

<line x1="1" y1="24" | x2="24" y2="1",
@ ./node_modules/ngx-joyride/esm5/ngx-joyride.esm.js 1:17918-17955
@ ./dist/server/main.bundle.js
@ ./server.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

1. install first this svg-inline-loader using this command
   "npm install svg-inline-loader --save-dev"
2. Then in your webpack-config.js file add this in module

   {
           test: /.svg$/,
           loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
       }